# How to make Parallel.For to queue its iterations sequentially?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

I have a for cycle. `Parallel.For`. And a lot of iterations. I want to utilize all the processor cores the environment have. But I really need the iterations to be queued sequentially.

For example, I have 100 iterations for `Parallel.For` to run, and 4 cores available. Appears that the first iterations to run are 0th, 25th, 50th, 75th. What I want is for them to be 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th, and when one of them is finished, the next should be 5th, then 6th and so on.

When I mess with the "degree of parallelism" parameter, it just divides the iteration range differently, for example 0th, 10th, 20th and so on. The only way I could achieve sequential queuing is by setting parallelism equal to the full number of iterations, so that they will at least start sequentially. But I assume it's not the most effective way as the excess processes will slow down the previously started ones.

So how do I queue the `Parallel.For` iterations to start in order, but not more of them at once than a specified number?

Comment: Why do you want to process sequencially? What I 2 ends before 1? Could this be a problem? If not: Why don't process 2 first and 1 after it?

Comment: I'm filtering a big ordered collection of data, but it may happen that all the results I need are in the first few chunks of the collection, and I need to maintain the order. I also want to have an option to finish at the moment I've already got enough results. If they're found in the chunks 1 to 4 then it's a waste of time to go though part 25, 50 and so on.

Comment: Either your tasks are completely independent of each other, in which case it doesn't matter which order they run, or they need to be run sequentially, so you cannot parallelise them. If you *really* want to do what you say, then you will have to create your own tasks, set them running one by one until you hit your maximum, then monitor them finishing so you can set the next one running.

Comment: Consider feeding chunks of data with size equal to your desired parallelism to the `Parallel` operations sequentially or you can use TPL DataFlow for this task. But note that the order inside parallelized chunks cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: Just saw your new comment. It's not clear how you expect to maintain order if you parallelise the processing. What happens if chunk 1,2,3 finish, 4 is still running but the results from chunk 5 get you to the limit?

Comment: Because I already took care about maintaining the order. What I need is not to waste time on the chunks on the other end of the collections if all the results I need can be found in the first few. Because I can't skip the results. It should be 1-2-3-4-5-6, but not 1-4-5-6-9245-30349.

Comment: If the chunk 5 will get me the final result, and chunk 4 will finish only after it, so be it. Just maybe there would be the chunks 6 and 7 in the processing, but they will not slow the whole process down anyways (cores counts).

Comment: I think you should be able to use a custom partitioner to achieve your desired behavior. This example looks promising (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-dynamic-partitions) but you should check out the main article as well (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl)

Comment: If your original data source is a `List` or array, you could also use `InterlockedIncrement` inside the `Parallel.For` to get the index of the element to process (and then you read it straight out of the array or list). This avoids the need for initialising the queue or locking (`InterlockedIncrement` has some locking - but it is much cheaper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a special order, you could use a `Queue` to ensure a first-in-first-out:

```
public static void DoSomething(int x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting " + x);
    Thread.Sleep((x%10) * 1000);
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Queue<int> myList = new Queue<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        myList.Enqueue(i);

    // This would be random if we'd use a List
    //Parallel.ForEach(myList, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, x => DoSomething(x));

    // This will get the right order. But 2 can still be faster than 1 if 2's thread is quicker. But generally you got your order.
    Parallel.For(
        0,  // We count from 0
        myList.Count,  // to max entries..
        new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },  // don't forget this one ;)
        (x) => { lock (myList) { int y = myList.Dequeue(); Console.WriteLine(y); DoSomething(y); } });
}
```

Have a look at the output. If two threads start parallel, you don't know the order. But generally the next one will be dequeued.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the wheels will fall off when dequeueing from multiple threads on a `Queue<T>`. `ConcurrentQueue<T>` FTW! Otherwise, a great idea.

Comment: Huh, this worth a shot, will try it.

Comment: @spender Jup. Forgot this. But `TryDequeue` can fail and would need a retry-loop. Added a `lock() {}` for the queue.

Comment: Let's say there are 100 items in a queue. If you call `TryDequeue` 100 times (which is what your code would do), it will never return `false`. `ConcurrentQueue` does seem a more natural choice than manual locking.

Comment: Got a cite/doc for this? All I found in documentation said that it `returns false` if it's not successful, but no reasons. It will surely return false if the queue is empty, but why not return `null` like `Queue<T>.Dequeue()`?

Comment: Okay I gave it a try and this does look like it works as intended. The funny thing is, however, that it doesn't really make a difference, maybe even slightly slower because of queue initializing on each run. So the messed up way of assigning the degree of parallelism as the number of iterations intended to run (be it even 1000) ackchually already works as I need it to, huh.

Comment: ...on the second thought, it still delivered some stable improvement (up to x1.7 speed) in particular scenarios, but not in all of them. So the queuing actually helps.

Comment: @yaapelsinko see my comment on the OP. You might be able to get what you need without sacrificing performance using a Partitioner

Comment: I'll post a second answer on monday. I built a worker class which queues and does jobs on demand..

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I did, thanks, looks like it's more I need to learn about all this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If the order of processing is important, then the `Parallel.For` is not suitable. You can switch to the [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) method, and feed it with an [`Enumerable.Range`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range) as source:

```
ParallelOptions options = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};

Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(1, 100), options, (int i) =>
{
    // Do something with i
});
```

This might still not be completely sequential, because of `Parallel`'s default partitioning strategy which is known as [chunk-partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl#kinds-of-partitioning). You can disable it with the [`Partitioner.Create`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create) method and the [`EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.enumerablepartitioneroptions) option:

```
ParallelOptions options = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};

OrderablePartitioner<int> partitioner = Partitioner
    .Create(Enumerable.Range(1, 100), EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);

Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, options, (int i) =>
{
    // Do something with i
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could first split the values to operate on like:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<int>> CreateDictionary()
{
    var rtnValue = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>()
    {
        { "0", new List<int>() },
        { "1", new List<int>() },
        { "2", new List<int>() },
        { "3", new List<int>() }
    };


    var rando = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (i < 25)
            rtnValue["0"].Add(rando.Next(-100, 100));

        if (i > 24 && i < 50)
            rtnValue["1"].Add(rando.Next(-100, 100));

        if (i > 49 && i < 75)
            rtnValue["2"].Add(rando.Next(-100, 100));

        if (i > 74 && i < 100)
            rtnValue["3"].Add(rando.Next(-100, 100));
    }

    return rtnValue;
}
```

Now lets have a method that does the work.

```
public static string processList(IList<int> param)
{
    return string.Join(", ", param);
}
```

And finally do the work in parallel like:

```
public void runInParallel()
{
    var DataToOperateOn = CreateDictionary();
    Parallel.For(0, DataToOperateOn.Count, i =>
    {
        processList(DataToOperateOn[i.ToString()]);
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you could accomplish about the same thing with Parallel.Invoke like:

```
public void runInParallel()
{
    var DataToOperateOn = CreateDictionary();
    Parallel.Invoke(
    () => { processList(DataToOperateOn["0"]); },
    () => { processList(DataToOperateOn["1"]); },
    () => { processList(DataToOperateOn["2"]); },
    () => { processList(DataToOperateOn["3"]); });
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't exactly what I'm doing it for. The job is to filter a small (up to 500 elements) ordered subset from a collection that is very big (hundreds of thousands) and is already ordered. The filtering condition can be quite basic, so that many of the elements at the very start of the big collection will fit. That's why I don't want to look at the middle before I'm certain there are not enough results at the beginning.